# Gravity right doesn't work

Tags: android, textview

I have a TextView with gravity="right".

In some devices this is working fine in other this doesn't work!!!

Device OK, Galaxy Note:

[image]

Device not OK, Galaxy tab 10", text are going to left when we have 2 lines and more:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a full support in arabic before android 4.0
check if this is the problem, try it on different versions of android

Comment: I agree maybe this is the answer, it is working on my galaxy note (android 4.1.2) and not working on my galaxy tab (android 3.1)

Answer (score 0):

If am not mistaken the right alignment will flip to the other side depending on the locale of the device, you can check for the locale, and if it's and RTL language just flip the gravity to the other side